# When is it possible to define a Kähler manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-forms, kahler-manifolds

I've started recently to learn about complex differential geometry and Kähler manifolds.

Let be $(M,J)$ a manifold with an almost complex structure embedded; I know that if we're able to define a closed (1,1) canonical form, then we can endow $(M,J)$ with a Kähler manifold structure.

Is it always possible to define a closed canonical form over any manifold like this? What are the necessary and sufficient conditions over the manifold or the inherent topological space?

Comment: I feel like there is a lot you could say about this. More than I can reasonably summarize in a short answer. Being Kahler comes with the entire "Kahler package", and characterizing them is interesting. For example, in dimension 2, it's equivalent to having first Betti number be even, but in general, much more complicated, because of e.g. Hironiaka's example of a family of compact complex manifolds where precisely one is non-Kahler.

Comment: You could try these notes: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~maxim/ih_intro.pdf

Comment: Your terminology is unclear. What is "embedded" here? Do you mean a *symplectic*  form rather than "canonical"? As for the simplest example of non-Kahler complex manifold, consider the Hopf torus, $S^3\times S^1$.